# Failed to load the LayoutLib: com/android/layoutlib/bridge/Bridge Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 how to solve?

Tags: java, android, xml, api, sdk

please help me. i was updated my android studio targeted version API level 28. all is ok but Rendering Problems. how to solve this?

Rendering Problems:
Failed to load the LayoutLib: com/android/layoutlib/bridge/Bridge : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "net.gurujibd.ajkerkhobor"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.+'
}
```

[image: Unsupported major.minor version 52.0]

[![Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> Error: more than one library with package name 'android.support.graphics.drawable'][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isAb5.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isAb5.png)

Comment: So the problem is that the JVM is attempting to load a class that is too new for it to understand.  One possible solution would be update the JVM ... to Java 8.   Check the release notes for the version of Android Studio + API level to see what version of Java is required.

Comment: my android studio version is 1.5.1 and it's api level is 28.

Comment: And what version of JVM?   I have added a link that explains how to use Android Studio with a Java 8 JVM.

Comment: resolved this problems by updating all of requirement. thanks